# Spring data mongodb override configuration

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, spring-data-mongodb

I have simple maven projects with `Spring-data-mongodb` project. And I need to specify (override) Database connection details. MongoDB databse runs on localhost with default settings (port=27017). I am trying to use `AppConfig`

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
public class AppConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "TestDatabase";
    }

    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        // wrong port on purpose
        return new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27007);
    }

}
```

My main file looks like this

```
  public class MongoApp {

  private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MongoApp.class);

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    MongoOperations mongoOps = new MongoTemplate(new MongoClient(), "database");
    mongoOps.insert(new Person("Joe", 34));

    log.info(mongoOps.findOne(new Query(where("name").is("Joe")), Person.class));

//    mongoOps.dropCollection("person");

  }
}
```

When I run project everything works fine but I it should not with this config.

project structure

```
main
-AppConfig.java
-MongoApp.java
-Person.java
```

Comment: Everythin is fine. Then what are you asking exactly? You want to get configurations from application.properties?

Comment: nope i know how to do that ... i just dont uderstand why is this working ... because specified port 27007 is wrong. My local db runs on 27017. So i think that my AppConfig is ignored

Comment: Did you try to fetch anything from db? Spring can establish connection lazily. So no connection exception till first request

Comment: Look at main file mongoOps.findOne(new Query(where("name").is("Joe")), Person.class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
I used this configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    public @Bean
    MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {
        return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient(), "mydb");
    }

    public @Bean
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {

        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());

        return mongoTemplate;

    }

}
```

And main file with `ApplicationContext`:

```
    public class MongoApp {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(MongoApp.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations)ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");

        mongoOperation.insert(new Person("Joe", 34));
        log.info(mongoOperation.findOne(new Query(where("name").is("Joe")), Person.class));
            //mongoOps.dropCollection("person");
    }
}
```